# Linq to SQL foreign key mapping

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do a basic lnq to sql foreign key mapping using attributes. This should be really simple but I'm having a hard time finding decent info on it on the net. Where am I going wrong?

Say for example you have a class named User with UserId, FirstName, LastName, Location on it. Location  is an object called Location

Location class has LocationId, StreetNum, Name, Suburb

How do I map that with Linq to Sql?

Here's what I'm trying

```
 [Column]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    private EntityRef<Location> _location;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your suburb")]
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_location", ThisKey = "LocationId", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public Location Location
    {
        get { return this._location.Entity; }
        set { this._location.Entity = value;
            LocationId = value.LocationId;
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error:
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Double which is a non-nullable value type.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try auto-generating your code using the designer from the definition in the database and look what the code generator spits out.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, somewhere you've used double datatype (StreetNum, maybe).
In the database corresponding column is marked with NULL flag. Try to use double? or Nullable<double> datatype for your properties.